# Silverlight app using browser http stack tries to read custom http header from server response

Tags: silverlight, clienthttpstack

I am working on a silverlight app that is using browser HTTP stack to communicate with the server (restful service). When the server responds to requests from this app, it uses custom HTTP headers to provide extra information for the client.

Unfortunately, we are unable to extract these custom headers in the silverlight app. It seems that the custom headers are removed by the browser HTTP stack, before we can process them.

Is this a known issue? Can we do anything to be able to read these custom HTTP header fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, the custom response headers are only supported in Client HTTP stack:

[How to: Specify Browser or Client HTTP Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920295%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)